# Accessing Database using SQL

Tags: sql

I am using SQL to access a database(table shown below with two columns `Inputted Value` and `VAL`) through my GUI software (`Siemens' WinCC`). I have achieved the task where user key in `24.5` and my script display the value 30 corresponding to the input. I have a case where user key in a value which is not in the table. Like user key in `26.5` so it should output interpolated value between `30` and `35`. Any suggestions?

```
Inputted Value
24.5
28
25

VAL
30
35
44
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Which `VAL` corresponds to which `Inputted Value`?

Comment: This question is unclear.

Comment: I am using access database. Inputted value 28 should output 35 from the VAL column.

Comment: did my answer work out in the end? It would be nice to have feedback...

Comment: Dear Koriander, As far as average calculation is concerned, Yes it does work correctly. But still the interpolation calculation is a question Mark. Thanks nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (tested) (revised for MS Access):

1) Create a first query called interpolation_left:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 AS id, [val] AS val_left
FROM TABS
WHERE [Inputted Value] < 'key'
ORDER BY [Inputted value] DESC;
```

2) Create a second query called interpolation_right:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 AS id, [val] AS val_right
FROM TABS
WHERE 'key' < [Inputted Value]
ORDER BY [Inputted value];
```

3) Create the final query by putting together the previous two queries

```
SELECT (val_left + val_right) / 2 as result
FROM   interpolation_left
INNER JOIN  interpolation_right
ON interpolation_left.id = interpolation_right.id
```

'key' is a parameter with the user keyed-in value.

Comment: Dear koriander, Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried the above code but it didn't work for me. I replaced all the parameters of the database in the above code for my case. My table name is "TAGS" and columns name are "Inputted Value" and "VAL" respectively. But it didn't work. Could you please suggest?

Comment: Dear Koriander, First two statements run fine, however when I run last statement it gives me error that it doesn't recognize the word "interpolation". Please suggest whether the syntax is fine?

Comment: yes the above is correct. Perhaps you are mixing underscore _ with minus -?

Comment: Dear Koriander, I have not mixed the negative sign and underscore for sure. I have pasted the same code above as it is in my SQL Query window in three different line and I receive this error poped up: "Microsoft Access Engine Database couldn't find the input table or query 'interpolation_left'. Make sure it exists and is spelled correctly. How can I send you the screenshot of my query entry and the error?

Comment: You need to create and save the two first queries in Access with the names interpolation_left and interpolation_right. Then the 3rd query will work (I have tested it as is, replacing 'key' with 26.5).

Comment: I did that even then it didn't work. Getting errors. Please check whether the below statements are ok?                                       interpolation_left = SELECT TOP 1 1 AS id, [VAL] AS val_left FROM TAGS WHERE [TAGNAME] < '7' ORDER BY [TAGNAME] DESC         
interpolation_right=SELECT TOP 1 1 AS id, [VAL] AS val_right FROM TAGS WHERE '7' < [TAGNAME] ORDER BY [TAGNAME];    
SELECT (val_left + val_right) / 2 as result FROM   interpolation_left INNER JOIN  interpolation_right ON interpolation_left.id = interpolation_right.id

Comment: Well, I suppose you are getting a different error, right? The structure is the same but you have changed [Inputed Value] to [TAGNAME] and you are using strings, "7". This query does not work well with numbers inside strings. TAGNAME must be of type number (single or double) and compare with TAGNAME < 7 (no quotes) or use a parameter.

Comment: @Khyzer, could you confirm that I have answered your question? At least it's working in my test.

Comment: Dear Koriander, I have tried almost everything in my VBS Script. Currently my following statement works fine :strSQL = "Select VAL from TAGS WHERE TAGNAME='"&lnputValue&"'" Following this syntax I tried to declare two interpolation variables as per your suggestion and a third valriable to save the result of the third statement. But still it doesn't seem to work. May I know how did you test the Statements to be working on your side? Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate.

Comment: I'm not using any vbs, just queries in ms access. And those queries can not work if you pass a string as I mentioned before. I would suggest to just use query objects to start with. When you get it to work you can put them in a script and even refer to query objects instead of using sql in code.

Comment: Dear Koriander, Could you please pass me the screenshot of the queries working at your side? I have tried first two queries, they work well but confused how to test the third query?

Comment: There you go: http://imgur.com/DKSUmH7

Comment: Dear Koriander, Thanks a lot for your guidance and efforts. I tried the same way as you showed in the attached screenshot. I am etting correct averages once I enter a number that is in the table. Like when I enter 4 the result of the interpolation is correct which is 14.5. However if I enter any value which is not in table's 1st column like 4.5, answer is empty, doesn't return any value. Please suggest.  http://i.imgur.com/icZjr3r.jpg

Comment: Dear Koriander, Thanks a lot for your guidance and efforts. I tried the same way as you showed in the attached screenshot. I am etting correct averages once I enter a number that is in the table. Like when I enter 4 the result of the interpolation is correct which is 14.5. However if I enter any value which is not in table's 1st column like 4.5, answer is empty, doesn't return any value. Please suggest.  http://i.imgur.com/JKGULFq.jpg

Comment: Two things: if the input value is 4, then the correct answer should be 14, right? Those queries were not done for exact match, only for range match. You can change them by using >= and <= instead of > and <, but it's not ideal. Instead, you should have a query for the exact match, if result is empty, then use interpolation. 2nd: for the value 4.5, it works fine for me: http://imgur.com/AR1sMO8. What is the data type for TAGNAME?

Comment: Dear Kriander, Data type for TAGNAME is number. In my case if I put <= and >= in my quries and input 4 then result is 14 otherwise it is 14.5. and if I input 4.5 still the result is empty, how to implement interpolation in that case :( ? Thanks

Comment: I get result 15.5 if I use <=4 in left query and >4 in the right query

Comment: Look carefully at your left and right queries: they are different in the wrong manner. interpolation_left has a "total" row making it a group by query. Remove it and make sure the SQL is like I provided to you.

Comment: Dear Koriander, Thanks for your suggestions. Using the following queries to extract x1,x2,y1,y2 and then using two point and slope intercept equations to perform interpolation. strSQL(0)="Select TOP 1 VAL FROM TAGS WHERE TAGNAME >= '"&lnputValue(0)&"' ORDER BY TAGNAME"
strSQL(1)="Select  TOP 1 VAL FROM TAGS WHERE TAGNAME <='"&lnputValue(0)&"' ORDER BY TAGNAME DESC"
strSQL(2)="Select TOP 1 TAGNAME FROM TAGS WHERE TAGNAME < '"&lnputValue(0)&"'ORDER BY TAGNAME DESC"
strSQL(3)="Select TOP 1 TAGNAME FROM TAGS WHERE TAGNAME >= '"&lnputValue(0)&"'"

Comment: great! could you tag my answer as accepted, thanks.

Comment: Dear Koriander, I am facing a strange problem now. My above quries work fine for every input except the input in the range 1.75-2.0 and 2.75-3. For example if I input 1.85 the value x2 it fetches from database is 10 instead of 2. Similiarly if I input 2.85 the value x2 it fetches from database is 20 instead of 2. in these cases the intepoltion results are incorrect. Please suggest.

Comment: Hi @KHYZER, I've been away. Have you been able to solve this issue? The only idea that comes to mind is the data type. The queries are really very simple, not much to go wrong. Run each subquery separately to see intermediate results.

Comment: Dear Koriander, Thank you so much to look into my problem. I am still unable to solve this issue. I tried to run each query seperately and works fine for every input except for the inputs in the range as I mentioned above. I am using data type as "Text" and it seems that if I use any other data type the connection between WinCC and Database doesn't work. Please suggest. Thank you once again.

Comment: You really have to use numbers for comparison, either by using numeric data types in the tables or by using the function cint to convert the string numbers to real numbers. The first option is the best one but you need to sort out the connection problem. But please create a different question if you have further issues.